# Why do I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in a line with perfectly valid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax-error

This is the line of code:

```
guess = Pmin+(Pmax-Pmin)*((1-w**2)*fi1+(w**2)*fi2)
```

`Pmin`, `Pmax`, `w`, `fi1` and `fi2` have all been assigned finite values at this point, so why is there an error?

When I remove that line from the code, the same error appears at the next line of code, again for no apparent reason.

```
def Psat(self, T):
    pop= self.getPborder(T)
    boolean=int(pop[0])
   
    P1=pop[1]
    P2=pop[2]
    if boolean:
        Pmin = float(min([P1, P2]))
        Pmax = float(max([P1, P2]))
        Tr=T/self.typeMolecule.Tc
        w=0.5*(1+scipy.tanh((10**5)*(Tr-0.6)))
        fi1=0.5*(1-scipy.tanh(8*((Tr**0.4)-1)))
        fi2=0.460*scipy.sqrt(1-(Tr-0.566)**2/(0.434**2)+0.494

        guess = Pmin+(Pmax-Pmin)*((1-w**2)*fi1+(w**2)*fi2)   # error here
    
        solution = scipy.optimize.newton(funcPsat,guess, args=(T,self))
```

Comment: I found the error, there was a missing bracket in one of the previous lines. Thanks for the help

Comment: Starting with Python 3.10, we get better error messages for this kind of thing. In this case, `SyntaxError: '(' was never closed`, and there's an arrow that points to the opening parenthesis.

Comment: I changed my mind and reopened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239668 . It's distinct enough that it shouldn't be considered a duplicate here.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For earlier versions of Python<sup>(1)</sup>, an error may reported on a line that *appears* to be correct. In that case, you should try commenting out the line where the error appears to be. If the error moves to the *next* line, there are two possibilities:

- Either *both* lines have a problem (and the second was hidden by the first); or
- The *previous* line has a problem which is being carried forward.

The latter is *more likely*, especially if commenting out the new offending line causes the error to move again.

For example, consider code like the following, saved as `prog.py`:

```
xyzzy = (1 +
plugh = 7
```

Python 3.8.10 will report an error on line 2, even though the problem is clearly caused by line 1:

```
pax> python3.8 prog.py
  File "prog.py", line 2
    plugh = 7
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code in your question has a similar problem: the code on the previous line to the reported error has unbalanced parentheses.

Annotated to make it clearer:

```
# open parentheses: 1  2             3
#                   v  v             v
fi2=0.460*scipy.sqrt(1-(Tr-0.566)**2/(0.434**2)+0.494
#                               ^             ^
# close parentheses:            1             2
```

There isn't really a *general* solution for this - the code needs to be analyzed and *understood*, in order to determine *how* the parentheses should be altered.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> For what it's worth, the new PEG parser introduced in Python 3.9 paved the way for much improved error messages (gradually improving from 3.10 thru 3.12). This includes correctly identifying in the source code *where* the error is:

```bash
pax> python3 prog.py
  File "prog.py", line 1
    xyzzy = (1 +
            ^
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed
```

Comment: It turns out that an analogous issue can be caused by omitting the `except` (or `finally`) block from a `try`. This causes `IndentationError` on the next line, because that unindented line isn't inside the `try` block nor the expected `except` block. Newer Python versions report an explicit `SyntaxError` calling out the missing block. Note that `IndentationError` **is a subclass of `SyntaxError`**.

Answer (score 9):

You're missing a close paren in this line:

```
fi2=0.460*scipy.sqrt(1-(Tr-0.566)**2/(0.434**2)+0.494
```

There are three `(` and only two `)`.

Comment: My case was categorized as "the previous line has a problem which is being carried forward" according to paxdiablo . What I did to find the error was by commenting line by line upward the code until the Syntax Error disappeared temporary. The last line that I gave comment mark was the one who cause error.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem, with a syntax error that I knew should not be a syntax error.  In my case it turned out that a Python 2 interpreter was trying to run Python 3 code, or vice versa; I think that my shell had a PYTHONPATH with a mixture of Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score -3):

I noticed that invalid syntax error for no apparent reason can be caused by using space in:

```py
print(f'{something something}')
```

Python IDLE seems to jump and highlight a part of the first line for some reason (even if the first line happens to be a comment), which is misleading.

Comment: f-string-invalid-syntax-in-python-3-5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182209/f-string-invalid-syntax-in-python-3-5

Comment: Does Python's error show the wrong line, or is this only an IDLE thing? Either way, this is a different issue than the one OP's experiencing, if you read their code.

Comment: While it makes sense here to have answers that show problems caused by other kinds of valid syntax, this is an example where the *version of Python used* causes the syntax *not* to be valid. This question, fundamentally, is about code becoming invalid *because of other parts of the code*.