# Syntax error in simple Python program with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax

I have this code:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: ")
if num%2 == 0:
    print("The number is even")

else:
    print("The number is odd")
```

Why do I get a syntax error on the `if` statement line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a SyntaxError (or an IndentationError) in a line with perfectly valid syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/why-do-i-get-a-syntaxerror-or-an-indentationerror-in-a-line-with-perfectly-val)

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if num%2 == 0:
    print("The number is even")

else:
    print("The number is odd")enter code here
```

Missing a ) on the line before.  Lots of times when you get syntax errors on a line it happens at that line or a line or a few lines **before** that, in your case it's looking for a matching paren.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score -2):

As stated by `@mikeb`, the error in on the previous line, where
`num = int(input("Enter a number: ")` should be
`num = int(input("Enter a number: "))`.
When you are looking for an error, always check the previous line as well.