# F String Invalid Syntax in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that *F Strings* were introduce in Python 3.6. For that I was getting error: *"Invalid Syntax"*

```py
DATA_FILENAME = 'data.json'
def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Shop = apps.get_model('shops', 'Shop')
    jsonfile = Path(__file__).parents[2] / DATA_FILENAME

    with open(str(jsonfile)) as datafile:
        objects = json.load(datafile)
        for obj in objects['elements']:
            try:
                objType = obj['type']
                if objType == 'node':
                    tags = obj['tags']
                    name = tags.get('name','no-name')
                    longitude = obj.get('lon', 0)
                    latitude = obj.get('lat', 0)
                    location = fromstr(F'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
                    Shop(name=name, location = location).save()
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

Error:

```
location = (F'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I used:

```py
fromstr('POINT({} {})'.format(longitude, latitude), srid=4326)
```

The error was removed and it worked for me. Then I found this library [future-fstrings](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings). Should I use it. Which will remove the above *"Invalid Error"*?

Comment: Format ("f") strings have not been introduced before Python 3.6.

Comment: Well, f-strings are only available since Python 3.6.

Comment: Why does the error message not match your code?

Comment: Probably just a copy-and-paste error.

Comment: @holdenweb It would be a strange copy-paste-error, that drops a statement in the middle.

Comment: Bytestring quantum tunnelling, most likely ;-). Just using the most charitable interpretation.

Comment: More Python crap that breaks basic I/O... The Python devs should get a Darwin award. How hard is to to make I/O "just work"?

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632). (I ended up establishing a different canonical from what I first expected.)

Answer (score 19):

For older versions of Python (before 3.6):

Using [`future-fstrings`](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings):

```
pip install future-fstrings
```

you have to place a special line at the top of your code:

```
coding: future_fstrings
```

Hence in your case:

```
# -*- coding: future_fstrings -*-
# rest of the code
location = fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})', srid=4326)
```