# "No module named pdfminer" with all of pdfminer.six,pdfminer, pdfminer2,pdfminer3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-3.5, pdfminer

I am using `Anaconda` with `Python=3.5` and have tried everything from

```
pip install pdfminer.six
pip install pdfminer
pip install pdfminer2
pip install pdfminer3
```

as well as the Anaconda and Conda-forge downloads. Everytime I try to import, it throws the same error. What should I be doing??

When I tried to use

```
>> pdf2txt.py  # to check if there is a file or not
```

using shell, it gave me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py35/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
  File "/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pdfminer/converter.py", line 120
    return f'(cid:{cid})'
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
>> pip list | grep pdfminer
```

gives me

**pdfminer           20191016**

It means that these is a file named but why is it not importing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182209/f-string-invalid-syntax-in-python-3-5

Comment: No it did not help at all

Comment: You did not read the discussion. pdfminer code uses f-strings which were introduced in python 3.6. You're at 3.5.