# Learning to code and a syntax error appears when I conduct nose tests, I can't see the error

Tags: python, testing, syntax, nose

I receivee a syntax error when I use nosetests on the following piece code.

I've checked the code to see whether it matches the description in the book and I don't see any errors. This is the segment of code I'm using:

```
    from nose.tools import *
    from ex47.game import Room


     def test_room():
         gold = Room ("GoldRoom",
                    """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                    door to the north."""
        assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
        assert_equal(gold.paths, [])

     def test_room_paths():
         center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
         north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
         south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

        center.add_paths(['north': north, 'south': south])
        assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
        assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

     def test_map():
         start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
         west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
         down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

        start.add_paths(['west': west, 'down': down])
        west.add_paths(['east': start])
        down.add_paths(['up': start])

       assert_eqaul(start.go('west'), west)
       assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
       assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

This is what the expected result should be:

```
     $nosetests
     ...

     Ran 3 tests in 0.008s

     OK
```

And this is the actual result that I get:

```
    E
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (ex47_tests.py, line 9))
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
        raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
       File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/nose/loader.py", line 417, in loadTestsFromName
         addr.filename, addr.module)
      File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
        return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
       File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
         mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
      File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, 
     in load_module
          return load_source(name, filename, file)
       File "/Users/alasdairkite/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, 
    in load_source
        module = _load(spec)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in 
    exec_module
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
       File "/Users/alasdairkite/Documents/Programming/LMPTHW/LPTHW/projects/Ex47/skeleton/tests/ex47_tests.py", line 9
assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Ran 1 test in 0.002s

     FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/syntax-error-invalid-syntax-for-no-apparent-reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a bracket.  Try this:

```
def test_room():
     gold = Room ("GoldRoom")
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north."""
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, [])
```

Comment: This should be actually be ```Room ("GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")```