# I am having a syntax error on a correct line for input command

Tags: python, syntax

[it automatically detects it as a string`

this is the error

```
input_msg = input('enter message:-')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`]
```

this is my code

```
import time
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided = "password"  
password = password_provided.encode() 
salt = b'salt_' 
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)

input_msg = input('enter message:-')

message = input_msg.encode()

time.sleep(15)

f = Fernet(key)

code = f.encrypt(message)

print(message)
```

i am using vs code and my python version is 3.7
i am unable to use input func and it automatically tells me that my variable is a string as the above image

Comment: Please can you post the full stack trace, You say something about a string, but the error you have is a syntax error, not a type error.

Comment: A Python syntax error has arguably nothing to do with `cryptography` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/syntax-error-invalid-syntax-for-no-apparent-reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a closing bracket on the line above:

```
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password) # need ) here
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a paren on the line above. Should be:

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

Answer (score 0):

On this line: `key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)` you need to add another `)` at the end.