# creating a dict within a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to get this output:

```
[{'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}}, {'B':{'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}}]
```

from this:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = ['A','B']
```

And i tried this:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = ['A','B']
main_list =[]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    db1 = dict(zip(list2,list1[i]))
    for j in range(len(list3)):
        db2 = dict(zip(list3[j],db1))
        main_list.append(db2)   
print(main_list)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `db1 = dict(zip(list2,list1[i])` is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Fixing that will allow your code to run but it won't give your desired output. However, perhaps that's enough to be able to explore the issue yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no apparent reason - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/syntax-error-invalid-syntax-for-no-apparent-reason)

Comment: i fixed it but still didn't give me the wanted output

Comment: update the question accrdingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done more compactly using the below list comprehension. Essentially you start by element-wise zipping `list3` (your keys) against `list1` which will have your sublists. Then for each of those pairs, you zip `list2` (which will be the inner keys) against the current sublist, which will serve as the values of the inner dictionary.

```
>>> [{k: dict(zip(list2, sub))} for k,sub in zip(list3, list1)]
[{'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}}, {'B': {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}}]
```

For what it's worth, the issue with your current code is simply a missing `)` above the line that you indicated. However, a more terse way to achieve your desired output would be using the above list comprehension.