# Getting Error: message SyntaxError: invalid syntax when open a txt in Python

Tags: python, text, syntax

`code here`

```
def button_clicked(self):
    self.lineedit.setText(
        open('test2.txt', 'r', encoding='uft_8')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        print(data))
```

**error message**
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Expected**
error resolution

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Syntax Error: invalid syntax' for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111/syntax-error-invalid-syntax-for-no-apparent-reason)

Comment: Please check how to call a function with multi variables first...

Answer (score 3):

Your are opening the file in the wrong place, try this:

```py
def button_clicked(self):
    f = open('test2.txt', 'r', encoding='uft_8')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    self.lineedit.setText(data)
```

also there is a better way to open read data from a file

```py
def button_clicked(self):
    with open('test2.txt', 'r', encoding='uft_8') as f
        data = f.read()
        self.lineedit.setText(data)
```